# When counting unique factors in a data frame, how do I retain a value from another vector?

Tags: r, date, vector, unique

The data from my data frame "lotsadates" looks like this:

```
>Date

1 2012-09-26
2 2012-09-26
3 2012-09-26
4 2012-09-27
5 2012-09-28
6 2012-09-28
```

There is a day_of_week vector of the same length:

```
> day_of_week

1 3
2 3
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 5
```

I am using the following to count the number of observations by date:

```
ndist <-tapply(1:NROW(lotsadates), 
               lotsadates$Date, 
               function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

So ndist looks like this:

> Obs / Date / ndist
>  
>   1 / 2012-09-26 / 3
>   2 / 2012-09-27 / 1
>   3 / 2012-09-28 / 2

But I want ndist to look like this:

> Date / ndist / day_of_week 
>  
>   1 / 2012-09-26 / 3 / 3
>   2 / 2012-09-27 / 1 / 4
>   3 / 2012-09-28 / 2 / 5

I think there is a fairly simple solution but I can't figure it out.  Your suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(plyr)
# assuming lotsadates has 2 columns, Date and day_of_week
ndist <- ddply(lotsadates, .(Date, day_of_week), summarise, n=length(Date))
```

Comment: This was very easy to do.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

A `data.table` approach for coding elegance

```
library(data.table)
# assuming lotsadates has 2 columns, Date and day_of_wee
DT <- as.data.table(lotsadates)
DT[, .N, by = list(Date, day_of_week)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(reshape2)
result <- dcast(lotsadates, Date ~., value.var='day_of_week')
result$day_of_week <- as.POSIXlt(result$Date)$wday
names(result)[2] <- "ndist"
> result
        Date ndist day_of_week
1 2012-09-26     3           3
2 2012-09-27     1           4
3 2012-09-28     2           5
```

Comment: Note: Be sure to `cbind` the `day_of_week` columns to your `lotsadates` data.frame for this to work.